# Does increasing the concentration of the anode electrolyte in a galvanic cell increase or decrease the voltage produced

Tags: experimental-chemistry, electrochemistry, electrolysis

Im in kind of a pickle here. I am using nernst equations to calculate the theoretical voltage produced for different concentrations of $\ce{Al(NO3)3}$.

Reaction: $$\ce{2Al(s) + 3Pb^{2+}(aq)⟶2Al^{3+}(aq) + 3Pb(s)}$$

Electrolytes are $\ce{Al(NO3)3}$ and $\ce{Pb(NO3)2}$.

I am using the Nernst equation $$E_{cell}=E^0-\frac{RT}{nF}\mathrm{ln}⁡(⁡Q)$$  and have the following calculation: $$E_{cell}=1.53-\frac{(8.314×293.7)}{(6×96500)}×\mathrm{ln}⁡\left(\frac{(.01)^2}{(0.1)^3} \right)$$

where $Q=[Al^{3+}]^2/[Pb^{2+}]^3$   is the ratio (products)/(reactants).

I am finding that using the Nernst equation, an increase in the concentration of $\ce{Al(NO3)3}$ leads to a decrease in voltage whereas according to my practical data im finding an increase in voltage.

Also, [according to this](https://www.enotes.com/homework-help/galvanic-cell-concentration-anode-solution-307953) an increase in concentration should lead to an increase in voltage.

Can anybody tell me what im doing wrong here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Well, the linked answer is completely wrong. Since this is an equilibrium process, an increase in the concentration of the product will make the reaction less spontaneous. In a galvanic cell, this translates to a smaller potential difference.

Comment: I've never heard of eNotes before, but judging by this example, what you did wrong was to trust the content on that site.